# How to make swipable segment tabs in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

I want to add more number of tabs, is there any solution to swipe across these tabs?

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="query" (ionChange)="showdata()">
<ion-segment-button value="slide1">
 TabTitle1
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide2">
 TabTitle2
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide3">
 TabTitle3
</ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: you mean like slides?

Comment: Exactly my problem is I want to add 6 Items in that segments , now I am able to add 4 segments only, that too if that title is a longer word, then it is displaying half of the word only. To avoid these I want that segment bar swipable. in this way https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2210672/13279507/b877dffa-dad8-11e5-9f1d-19b48349c1ed.gif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below CSS, this will work

for Reference :- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7202

```
home {
.swiper-slide {
overflow-y: scroll;
display: block;
}

ion-segment {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: auto;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    ion-segment-button.segment-button {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 100px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
/*
ion-segment-button.segment-button {
    display: inline-block!important;
    min-width: 100px!important;
    width: auto!important;
    }*/

}
```

Comment: Thank you..works without any glitch, and smoothly too. And usually ionic-CSS3 animations are slow in device, I mean they are not as smooth as javascript animations. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This works like charm. But segment does not swipes along with the content. Can you help me in this.

Comment: Use swiper function to get that

Comment: this works great. Maybe something worth to mention: if you have troubles making the swipe possible check if you have a `tab` event on your `ion-segment-button` - It didn't work for me until I changed it to a `click` event

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`ion-scroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) for it.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX=true>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="query" (ionChange)="showdata()">
<ion-segment-button value="slide1">
 TabTitle1
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide2">
 TabTitle2
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide3">
 TabTitle3
</ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment> 
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Segments disappeared after adding this. Did it work in your case ? can u share your exactly working code ?

Comment: @DEEPANKUMAR I will try and create a plunker and update the answer.. wont be able to do it right now though..

Comment: @DEEPANKUMAR you need to specify height to `ion-scroll`

Answer (score 0):

[duplicate [Ionic - how to slide ion-segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490378/ionic-how-to-slide-ion-segments#answer-51437755])

simple and easy even logic only in the html, no need JS custom code.

clean, only using ionic feature.
you can implement ion-slides and ion-segment that listen to 1 variable say `segment`

Toolbar: bind to segment, and listen ionChange

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment (ionChange)="slides.slideTo(segment)" [(ngModel)]="segment"  color="warning">
      <ion-segment-button value="0">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="1">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

ion-slides:
capture the slide event, assign segment to current active index

```
 <ion-slides #slides (ionSlideWillChange)="segment=''+slides.getActiveIndex()">
   <ion-slide>
     profile,
     hello <span *ngIf="this.userProvider.userData">{{this.userProvider.userData.name}}</span>

   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     second

   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     third

   </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```