# Ionic - how to slide ion-segments?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I slide to switch segment like many apps in ionic? I can't find any api in ionic official documentation. I can only find [this](https://gist.github.com/aarjithn/d282b019f6046f0de2f0ded623554313) useful thread.

But it does notseem perfect. Is there some better solution?

ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/wdMMpq?editors=1010

Comment: Are you using some js framework or just vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

Sliding segments or tabs have long been expected in ionic but it's finally here. Check this ultimate tutorial on getting it implemented https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-swipeable-tabs-to-an-ionic-application/

Answer (score 0):

simple and easy, no need JS custom code. you can implement ion-slides and ion-segment that listen to 1 variable say `segment`

Toolbar: bind to segment, and listen ionChange

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment (ionChange)="slides.slideTo(segment)" [(ngModel)]="segment"  color="warning">
      <ion-segment-button value="0">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="1">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

ion-slides:
capture the slide event, assign segment to current active index

```
 <ion-slides #slides (ionSlideWillChange)="segment=''+slides.getActiveIndex()">
   <ion-slide>
     profile,
     hello <span *ngIf="this.userProvider.userData">{{this.userProvider.userData.name}}</span>

   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     second

   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     third

   </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

Comment: but there are lots of issue  with that solution.

Comment: Which problems are there for example?